# sitecore 7 multi datasource field

Tags: sitecore, datasource, sitecore7, treelist

I have a treelist field that I want to set the datasource to 3 folders p.e.:

```
/sitecore/Website/News/
/sitecore/Website/Events/
/sitecore/Website/Articles/
```

Under the website item there are more "folders".

I've searched and spent few hours trying different approaches but none seemed to work.

Is this possible? Do I need to extend the field?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **IncludeTemplatesForDisplay** parameter to filter the items based on templates:

```
DataSource=/Sitecore/Content/Home&IncludeTemplatesForDisplay=News Folder,News,Event Folder,Event
```

**IncludeTemplatesForDisplay** parameter accepts comma separated templates names, you might need to include parent folder templates names too so that it appear in treelist.

Hope this helps

Comment: I would add that there is also an `ExcludeTemplatesForDisplay`, `IncludeTemplatesForSelection`, an `ExcludeTemplatesForSelection`, an `IncludeItemsForDisplay`, and an `ExcludeItemsForDisplay` parameter, all of which are described and demonstrated with an example in my [blog post](http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2014/june/26/constraining-the-sitecore-7-multilist-and-treelist-fields-with-and-without-search). However, this is not really what he asked for.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Excellent Blog! lots of useful information in one place +1

Comment: Thanks both. I'll try the approach with excludes/includes. However the folders are sharing the same template - I can duplicate them. I was looking for something slightly different but if I don't have any other idea I'll go with that. Thanks mate.

Comment: I ended up using Ahmed's suggestion. Creating duplicate templates for the news, events and articles folders, Including those templates on the datasource in addition to the articles, news and events templates themselves. I also exclude the folder templates from selection as Zachary pointed. Thank you both DataSource=/Sitecore/Content/Website&IncludeTemplatesForDisplay=News Folder,Articles Folder,Events Folder,Article page,Events page,News page&ExcludeTemplatesForSelection=News Folder,Articles Folder,Events Folder

Answer (score 5):

A while back I wrote a [blog post](http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2014/june/26/constraining-the-sitecore-7-multilist-and-treelist-fields-with-and-without-search) about the different ways you can control the Datasource of your multilist and treelist fields (with and without search). The third technique listed for fields with search is what I think you are looking for:

**Search in two or more places of the content tree (Fields with Search):**

```
StartSearchLocation={110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}&Filter=_path:110d559fdea542ea9c1c8a5df7e70ef9|_path:3d6658d8a0bf4e75b3e2d050fabcf4e1
```

For your implementation:

```
StartSearchLocation={Website.ID}&Filter=_path:[News.ID (guid form; no brackets)]|_path:[Events.ID (guid form; no brackets)]|_path:[Articles.ID (guid form; no brackets)]
```

**Search in two or more places of the content tree (Fields without Search):**

If you are using a Multilist field (without search) then I would do the following:

```
DataSource=/path/to/source/1|/path/to/source/2
```

For your implementation:

```
DataSource=/sitecore/website/news|/sitecore/website/events|/sitecore/website/articles
```

I would also add that the *Treelist with Search* field has been deprecated in later versions of Sitecore 7, so if that is the field that you are using then I advise changing to the *Multilist with Search* field. If you are using a standard *Treelist* field, then Ahmed's answer may be viable as well, depending on your use case.

Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck, and happy coding! :)

Comment: Zachary thanks mate. Awesome answer! And I had a look at you blog and I'll be visiting it in the future! Good stuff. I cant put your suggestion to work though... When I try to set multiple datasources it shows the all content tree. (I've tried the 2nd one without the search). Am I missing anything?

Comment: Let me know your version information and I'll investigate. It is valid syntax for the data source but it could be a Sitecore bug.

Comment: In this instance I'm using sitecore 7 rev. 130424

Comment: And is the field a Treelist or Multilist?

Comment: I have updated my post as I made a mistake when I wrote it by stating that the 2nd option works for the Treelist field, for which I know it does not work. I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Zachary, now it makes sense. However I have implemented Ahmed's suggestion and it seems to meet the requirements (I prefer not to change to a multi-list at this point). That said, this is fantastic info. I'll definitely apply those techniques in future projects. Thanks

Comment: No problem at all. Glad you found a solution :)